# Altair changes order of legend when saving data to disk vs. storing data in the plot

Tags: python, altair

Consider the following dataframe created with the code snipped attached at the end of this question:

```
    A           B           C
0   1.624345    -0.611756   2
1   -1.072969   0.865408    1
2   1.744812    -0.761207   2
3   -0.249370   1.462108    2
4   -0.322417   -0.384054   11
5   -1.099891   -0.172428   1
6   0.042214    0.582815    1
7   1.144724    0.901591    11
8   0.900856    -0.683728   11
9   -0.935769   -0.267888   2
```

I want to create a scatter plot using the `A` and `B` columns and color the plot by `C`.
Running

```py
alt.Chart(randf).mark_point(size=100, filled=True).encode(
    x="A", y="B", color="C:N"
).properties(width=200, height=200)
```

I get the following chart with the legend being sorted 1, 2, 11:

[image]

But, I am often in a situation where the data is large and I don't want to embed it into the plot and store it on disk instead. I then usually run

```py
import os
from toolz.curried import pipe

def csv_dir(data, data_dir="altairdata") -> None:
    os.makedirs(data_dir, exist_ok=True)
    return pipe(data, alt.to_csv(filename=data_dir + "/{prefix} -{hash}.{extension}"))

alt.data_transformers.register("csv_dir", csv_dir)
alt.data_transformers.enable("csv_dir", data_dir="./.temporary_altair_data/")
```

Rerunning the same plot again, it now looks like this:
[image]

I.e., the order of the color is now 1, 11, 2. More generally, it treats the numbers like words and tries to sort them alphanumerically (at least that is my observation).

**Is there a way to have the correct order of the legend while still saving data to disk?**

Full code to reproduce:

```py
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
import numpy as np 
import os
from toolz.curried import pipe


np.random.seed(1)
randf = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 3), columns=list("ABC"))
randf["C"] = np.random.choice([1, 2, 11], 10)

chart1 = alt.Chart(randf).mark_point(size=100, filled=True).encode(
    x="A", y="B", color="C:N"
)
chart1
```

followed by

```py
def csv_dir(data, data_dir="altairdata") -> None:
    os.makedirs(data_dir, exist_ok=True)
    return pipe(data, alt.to_csv(filename=data_dir + "/{prefix} -{hash}.{extension}"))

alt.data_transformers.register("csv_dir", csv_dir)
alt.data_transformers.enable("csv_dir", data_dir="./.temporary_altair_data/")

chart2 = alt.Chart(randf).mark_point(size=100, filled=True).encode(
    x="A", y="B", color="C:N"
)
chart2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a weird bug. But I managed to find a workaround. The trick is to use `transform_filter` by passing possible values of `C` one at a time.

```
def csv_dir(data, data_dir="altairdata") -> None:
    os.makedirs(data_dir, exist_ok=True)
    return pipe(data, alt.to_csv(filename=data_dir + "/{prefix} -{hash}.{extension}"))
alt.data_transformers.register("csv_dir", csv_dir)
alt.data_transformers.enable("csv_dir", data_dir="./.temporary_altair_data/")
chart2 = alt.Chart(randf).mark_point(size=100, filled=True).encode(
    x=alt.X("A:Q"), 
    y=alt.Y("B:Q"), 
    color=alt.Color('C:N'),
).transform_filter( # get only the possible values of C
    {'field': 'C', 'oneOf': np.sort(randf.C.unique())}
)
chart2
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think I like the idea to transform the data. I do however prefer to run `.transform_calculate(intC = "toNumber(datum.C)")` and then just use `intC` as my color column. Would you know if this is actually a bug that needs to be reported?

Comment: This problem also goes away when using `alt.to_json` instead of `alt.to_csv` when saving the data to disk.